# Set strings in files as variable

Tags: loops, batch-file

I need help with creating a loop. The loop should take the first string in the file "filenames.txt" set that sting as a variable then execute a script including the variable, and repeat until it has done all the string in "filenames.txt".

Comment: Show us what you have done so far http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/225842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f %%a in (filenames.txt) do (
  call "my script.bat" "%%~a"
)
```